# How to override a style in simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, simple-form

I have this simple_form

```
      = f.association :offence_categories, collection: OffenceCategory.where(prefix: ''), as: :check_boxes, wrapper_html: {class: 'buttons buttons-offence_categories'}, label: ''
```

It's outputting a bullet before the label due to the check_boxes class

[image]

```
&::before
    content: ''
    width: 8px
    height: 8px
    border: 2px solid #999
    display: block
    float: left
    position: absolute
    top: 12px
    left: 10px
    +border-radius(8px)
```

I don't want to create another class just to change that. I'd like to make a local style change in the form to remove the %before

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the problem wasn't really a style. The bullet just meant it was required.

I just added `required: false` and the bullet was gone.